# Prove that the infinity norm of a matrix with matrix elements is equal to one for a special case

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, matrix-norms

Consider the following $3$x$3$ matrix which contains matrix elements:

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
M & N & 0 \\
N & M & N \\
0 & N & M 
\end{bmatrix} \tag 1$$

where:

$$M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1-2a-2b & a & 0 \\
a & 1-2a-2b & a \\
0 & a & 1-2a-2b 
\end{bmatrix} \tag 2$$

and:

$$N = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & b 
\end{bmatrix} \tag 3$$

where $a$ and $b$ are known non-zero positive constants. The infinity norm of matrix $A$ is the maximum sum of one of its rows.
The way I understand this, the infinity norm of matrix $A$ is:

$$ ||A||_{\infty}=|N|+|M|+|N| = 2|N| + |M| \tag 4 $$

On this [link](https://homework.study.com/explanation/in-terms-of-matrices-what-does-absolute-value-mean.html#:%7E:text=Absolute%20value%20of%20a%20matrix,a%2021%20%C3%97%20a%2012%20), I found out that the absolute value of a matrix is actually its determinant.

According to the Sarrus rule, the determinant of matrix $M$ is:

$$|M| = \det(M) = -4a^3 + (10-20b)a^2 - (1-2b)6a - (2b - 1)^3 \tag 5$$

and the determinant of matrix $N$ is:

$$|N| = \det(N) = b^3 \tag 6$$

By inserting expressions $(5)$ and $(6)$ into equation $(4)$, I have obtained:

$$||A||_{\infty}= -4a^3 + 10a^2-6a -6b^3+12b^2-6b - 20a^2b - 24ab^2 +24ab + 1 \tag7$$

I found out on page $[6]$ of [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231808979_Convergence_and_stability_analysis_of_an_explicit_finite_difference_method_for_2-dimensional_reaction-diffusion_equations#fullTextFileContent) paper, that if:

$$  1 - 2a - 2b \geq 0 \tag8$$

then the infinity norm of matrix $A$ is:

$$||A||_{\infty} = 1 \tag9$$

However, when I insert $b=0.5-a$ into equation $(7)$, I do not get that the infinity norm of matrix $A$ is one.

My question is, what am I doing wrong here? How can I prove that if
$ (1 - 2a - 2b) \geq 0 $, then the infinity norm of matrix $A$ is one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inf-norm of a matrix is maximum of row sums, i.e.:
$$\| A\|_\infty  = \max_{1\leq i \leq n} \sum_{j=1}^n |A_{i,j}| $$
and there's no relation like, $\|A\|_\infty = |N|+|M|+|N|$. and showing determinant of matrix ($det(A)$) as absolute value ($|A|$) is just a symbol, and it's not even common.

look for row of $A$. because $|a|$ and $|b|$ are positive having more of these elements increase row sum. element $|1-2a-2b|$ appears on all rows exactly once. so the maximum value happens in middle row of $A$ ,middle row of $M$ (because both $a$ and $b$ appears twice):
$$
\| A \|_\infty = |1-2a-2b|+2|a|+2|b|
$$
$a$ and $b$ are positive and if $1-2a-2b \geq 0$ :
$$
\| A \|_\infty = 1-2a-2b+2a+2b = 1.
$$

Comment: Hello Abolfazi, is it possible to pick three matrices of the same row of the main matrix and then to pick different rows of the submatrices when calculating the infinity norm?

Comment: The answer is no. because we are searching for maximum in row sums of main matrix $A$. if you choose for example first row of $N$ then second row of $M$ and third row of $N$ in middle block of $A$. it's no longer a row in A. so it cannot be among the set that we're searching for maximum. so it can't be $\|A\|_\infty$ eaither. note that $A$ here is in fact 9x9 real matrix not a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is clear to me now 